# Wildfly 9.0.2 on AIX server : application deploys but don't load for customers

Tags: jsf-2.2, wildfly-9

We have a JEE application ( with JSF 2.2 PF & RF ) that we have deployed for many of our customers. 
We have it deployed on jboss 4, wildfly 8 and recently we HAD to use wildfly 9.0.2 on an AIX environment. 
The application is deployed without issues but when accessing it the browser keeps fetching. On my laptop it actually work "sometimes" but the main issue I found is some images keeps fetched with status pending. I tried many browsers so I don't think it's browser related, it's not application related I can guess too. 
I gave file access rights to the files.
Any ideas or suggestions plz ?

Comment: So it works using Wlidfly 9.0.2 on windows?

Comment: Yes, I have it working, users can get in and get served, but not on the AIX

Comment: Any stack traces, errors, etc?

Comment: No errors at all. I noticed that the pages actually load with the HTML content and all but itt just doesn't render on some machines, it seems like number of connections is limited on the server or something like that but I had a  jboss 4 running an old version of my app

Comment: Ensure on AIX that you have sufficient file descriptors. It could be you are chocking off IO to the browser from the server. That's a guess given what little information I have. You did mention connections which are file descriptors (FD)'s on Unix/AIX.